# Using ForceCommand script for making session transcripts breaks SCP

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have the following line in `sshd_config` to make a transcript of every session:

```
ForceCommand script -q "/transcripts/test_transcript" -c "{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:=bash}"
```

SSH works as expected but when I try to SCP, it hangs at this point:

```
$ scp -v user@localhost:~/test .

# Lots of debug lines describing key exchange and auth

debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f ~/test
```

If I remove the line with `ForceCommand` from `sshd_config`, SCP works fine.

I assume this is not an uncommon pattern for making session transcripts and tried searching for a solution to this problem. As you can imagine it can be hard to find links that mention [script](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html), the utility *to make a typescript of a terminal session* from *util-linux* package, and not some other script.

Comment: *OpenSSH* devs [have long considered `scp` *outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed*](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0) so you might just want save yourself the effort of fixing all the edge cases. *sftp* and *rsync* have fewer unexpected shell interactions.

Comment: Do you really need to log the whole session? Or is it sufficient to just log what commands the user executed?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am open to looking at an alternative approach. What do you suggest?

Comment: You can try [tlog](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/recording_sessions/index) session recording if your distro supports it, or use the audit system to [log all commands that users run](https://serverfault.com/a/1036183/126632)

Comment: @anx Just tried using both sftp and rsync. Similar issues.